# Butcher tableau in Runge Kutta methods

Tags: matrices, runge-kutta-methods

I'm studying RK methods using Butcher tableau. 
I do not understand what this means. Can anyone explain what is the notation? 
[RK Butcher tableau matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoTGF.png)
It seems like matrices multiplication but MM does not look like that. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a scheme to hold the parameters of the method, just as a general matrix is a scheme to hold the coefficients of a linear map.
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\color{red}{c_1}&\color{green}{a_{11}}&\cdots&\color{green}{a_{1s}} \\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
\color{red}{c_s}&\color{green}{a_{s1}}&\cdots&\color{green}{a_{ss}} \\
\hline
&\color{blue}{b_1}&\cdots&\color{blue}{b_s}
\end{array}

If you have seen a general Runge-Kutta method, you should have seen these parameters applied in their correct place,
\begin{alignat}{1}
\vec k_i&=\vec f\bigl(t+\color{red}{c_i}h, &\vec y&+\sum_{j=1}^s \color{green}{a_{ij}}\vec k_jh\bigr),~~~
i=1,...,s,\\
\vec y_{+1}&=&\vec y&+\sum_{i=1}^s \color{blue}{b_i}\vec k_ih
\end{alignat}
So in some sense there is some kind of matrix-vector multiplication done with the coefficients $a_{ij}$.